# Repeat rows of a dataframe dependent on column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with several columns of which one with frequencies (see code below). I would like to insert rows depending on the frequencies mentioned in that column.

I have tried code like this:

```
df %<>% rowwise() %>%
    slice(rep(1:n(), .$lengte))
```

and variations on this, but non seem to work exactly the way I want

```
# sample of original dataframe
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,1,2,2), y = c(0,1,0,1), frequency = c(2,3,4,5))
```

The expected output would be:

```
dfout <- data.frame(x = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2), y = c(0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1))
```

Comment: `df %>%  
  slice(rep(seq_len(n()), frequency)) %>% 
  select(-frequency)
`

Comment: Thank you.```df %>% uncount(frequency) ``` was the solution